# @require-ing jQuery overwrites the page's $ variable

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm `@require`-ing jQuery for my Greasemonkey script with this line in my script file:

```
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

and it works quite well; I can use `$('#id')` to access the DOM.

However, the `$` variable of the 'real' page is modified (where `$` is jQuery 1.2.xx):
I get an error that `$.include` is not defined.

I thought the sandbox model of Greasemonkey would prevent that the variables of the target-page are overwritten?

How can I ensure that the inclusion of javascript libraries does not affect the 'real' website, but only my Greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Greasemonkey 1.0, radically changed the way the sandbox works](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant), busting thousands of scripts.  See also, [jQuery in Greasemonkey 1.0 conflicts with websites using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery).

This is a huge problem, and I hope you will join me in voicing your opinion/experiences on [the principle bug report for this issue](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1614).

Meanwhile, restore the sandbox to your script, and resolve the `$` conflict, by editing your **[Metadata Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) to end with the following lines**:

```js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design change introduced in GM 1.0,
    It restores the sandbox.
*/
```

Specifying a `@grant` value (other than `none`) reactivates the sandbox.

---

You might also consider switching to [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/), which has offered superior features and performance in the past, and does not suffer from this new sandbox behavior.

Answer (score 3):

See [`jQuery.noConflict();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/); it explains a lot.

EDIT:
Found ["Greasemonkey 1.0 + jQuery: Broken, with Workaround"](http://www.greasespot.net/2012/08/greasemonkey-10-jquery-broken-with.html) on searching.

Possible solution:

```
 this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Doing that, probably will implicitly specify that $, jQuery will be available in your script's namespace.

Comment: calling `unsafeWindow.$.noConflict()` does not bring back the 'old' jQuery version but after this call `$` is `undefined`. Why is is replaced in the first place?

Comment: because, through `unsafeWindow`, you are accessing the page's js. I think you want to do `$.noConflict();` on the userscript.

Comment: not really: the `$.include` not defined error is raised by the page's js.

Comment: I don't believe the `noConflict()` hack works in all cases (but I'm not going to work up a test case right now). It's the wrong approach, the most robust solution is to restore the sandbox.