# Tampermonkey - Refused to load the script...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, tampermonkey, content-security-policy

I'm trying to run a Tampermonkey script in Chrome on Facebook to customise my Facebook page.

I can run some simple script, but I can't load jQuery.

> Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl".

This is my code:

```
// Loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "window.jQ1=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();"; // jQ1 replaces $ to avoid conflicts.
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() {
  // empty for now, but won't even run
}

addJQuery(main);
```

Is there a way for me to use jQuery?

I also tried pasting the source inline but got this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: That's the wrong way to use jQuery, anyway.  For Tampermonkey (and whenever possible) [`@require` it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12250892/331508). (Or, see the second approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508) if you want to keep maximum cross-platform support -- although the CSP makes that irrelevant in this case).  If you do that, then Facebook's extra-tight CSP becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Brock! I replaced it with @require and it solved the problem!