# How to use waitForKeyElements to display information after select images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I wrote a script that adds the number, contained in the image source URL, to the page. It works great!

But, I also want it to run on a page that has AJAX-driven tabs.
I've tried playing around with `waitForKeyElements` but I can't figure out how to make it work, and I don't understand jQuery.

When I use `#dolls` it puts all contents of all tabs on the page... when I use `div.dolls` it disables the button to load the dolls.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Dex# of Pokedolls
// @namespace   http://trueidiocy.us
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=collection
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=giveaway
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=regional
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=shop
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=local&market=sell*
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=local&market=buy*
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/trainercard.php?trainer=*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

 waitForKeyElements (
 "div.dolls"           //also tried #dolls
, showdexno
);

function showdexno (jNode) {
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');     

for (var i = imgs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (imgs[i].src.indexOf('overworld') > -1) {
     var textNode = document.createElement('b');

var numtext=imgs[i].src.match(/\d+/g)

  textNode.innerHTML = numtext;    
  imgs[i].parentNode.appendChild(textNode, imgs[i]);     
 }
} 
}
```

I'm probably just not using the right syntax or something, but I'm totally lost.

I'm testing the script on [**this page**](http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/trainercard.php?trainer=10220), and it needs to trigger when the <kbd>Load Pokédolls</kbd> button is clicked on the *Pokédolls* tab.

You can view that target page without having to login.

I'm assuming that after I get this working I would just throw everything into an if statement:

```
 If location is trainer card wait for tab
 else just run the code
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  How do I use `waitForKeyElements` for this?  Or is there another way?

ETA: one more problem... On one page this shows the numbers right next to the pictures which is perfect - BUT - on other pages that have text under the images it adds it to the existing text. How do I make it be right next to the picture every time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I *think* I see what you are trying to do. But first, the question code has two big problems:

1. The script uses jQuery, but [the target page](http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/trainercard.php?trainer=10220) also uses jQuery.  So, when the script operates [in `@grant none` mode, either the script will crash, or the page will crash, or both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12983455/331508).  Defaulting to `@grant none` was a colossal mistake by the lead GM dev and, even if you are not using jQuery, you would be wise to avoid that mode.  Otherwise, your script will crash, it's just a matter of what future change does it in.
2. Fixed: <strike>`waitForKeyElements` is passed a callback function named `showdexno`, but there is no `showdexno` defined in the script!  (or on the page that I checked.)</strike>

`waitForKeyElements()` operates by looking for elements that match the selector and then feeding those elements, *one at a time*, to the callback function.  This means that things like `getElementsByTagName` or seldom needed in the callback.

For example, if you wanted to act on a bunch of images like this:

[image: target images]

You [would determine the HTML structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508), paying attention to any `id` or `class` attributes.  In this case, it looks like:

```
<div id="dolls">
  <center>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="attached" title="Quantity = 5" src="http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/dex/images/icon/overworld/1.png">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img class="attached" title="Quantity = 18" src="http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/dex/images/icon/overworld/2.png">
        </td>
... ...
```

And you apparently want only those images that have `overworld` in the `src`.

So, a good CSS/jQuery selector to *choose* might be `#dolls td > img.attached[src*='overworld']`.

The jNode passed to your `waitForKeyElements` callback would then be the image itself.  Images are passed in one at a time.

Putting it all together, a script to append the png file number would be like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Dex# of Pokedolls
// @namespace   http://trueidiocy.us
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=collection
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=giveaway
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=regional
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=shop
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=local&market=sell*
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/dolls.php?action=local&market=buy*
// @include     http://www.thepikaclub.co.uk/adopt/trainercard.php?trainer=*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements (
    "#dolls td > img.attached[src*='overworld']", 
    appendImageNumber
);

function appendImageNumber (jNode) {
    var numtext = jNode.attr ("src").match (/\d+/g);

    jNode.after ('<b>' + numtext + '</b>');
}
```

---

Eliminate the `.attached` if you want more (¿all?) of the images.

Reference:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery `.after()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=after)

Comment: I goofed in my code above... in my script get_span_content was showdexno... but I had already deleted it cause it didn't work so forgot to change in post what I copied from example... I'll fix that now... and yeah I thought the 2 jquerys could cause probs but couldn't find what I'd read about it

Comment: Greasemonkey automatically added the grant line... I just recently updated from .92 (I think...9 something anyways) and think I'll just leave out that line... all my old scripts work fine without it.

Comment: Working pretty good... but yeah I need all the doll images to show numbers... stinking trade system requires you to type the dex# of the doll you want to trade for, and if you don't play pokemon you have no idea what any of those dolls are... would it look like `"#dolls td > img[src*='overworld']"`

Comment: You need the grant line, `@grant GM_addStyle`, for sure for this page.  You would be wise to use that line in all your scripts, even if they appear to work (for now).  And, yes, `"#dolls td > img[src*='overworld']"` is what it would look like.

Comment: I noticed I needed that... now my only problem is that I added an `if` to check and run that version if it's on the trainer card page... but my `else {
  appendImageNumber
}` doesn't work on the non-ajax pages... I could use my previous code on those pages - except the placement of the text wasn't where I wanted it... God, I wish jQuery didn't confuse me so bad - js, basic, php, no problem... just something about jQuery...  back to trying to solve this part of the problem before someone answers and beats me to it lol

Comment: Oh, and for some reason this only works if I use a link to go to the page... if I refresh the page the load dolls button is grayed out...

Comment: Actually, waitForKeyElements will work on non ajax pages too.  You might have to adjust the selector for them though. You can have more than waitForKeyElements call in a script. ... The button being greyed out looks like something that the site might be doing on purpose.  It's easily defeated though (remove the `disabled` attribute).  Open new questions for these new wrinkles, if necessary.

Comment: Okay, thanks... I thought that the button problem didn't happen before the script, but when I turned it off it still did it... it IS a slightly buggy site...

Comment: Thanks for the edits... but next time could you maybe leave just a little of my personality in there please? lol

Comment: Okay, but pretty sure that's against SO policy. ;)  Also, we're tech nerds, tangential chatter annoys us. Just the facts, Ma'am, as simply and clearly as you can state them.  The exceptions are mostly on [meta], like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152754/148310).