# jQuery conflict between Greasemonkey script and page

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm writing an add-on for Greasemonkey and using jQuery 1.9.1 (via `@require`).

But there's already jQuery 1.1.2 on the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" >...
```

When I run the script it says

> "TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined".

I tried adding jQuery migrate to the Greasemonkey script - but it's still not working.

I think I need to replace the old jQuery version with the newest on the website dynamically. Is this possible (BTW. jQuery isn't actually used there a lot)?

Comment: I found this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: See ["jQuery in Greasemonkey 1.0 conflicts with websites using jQuery"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery) for the correct approach.