# jQuery.noConflict(); for userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

Hello I'm trying to add jQuery to my Userscript that I'm creating.

I've tried:

```
$ = jQuery = window.jQuery;
```

Doesn't work $ is undefined. My other choice is:

```
$ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
```

Which works and all, but I receive this error:

```
Unexpected token e
```

That's not even part of my code, it points to something on the website. However, I noticed that the website I'm creating a userscript for uses this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Is that the cause of this? And I can't import the jQuery library because I'm trying to make custom emotes for a shoutbox which uses XMLHttpRequests(AJAX) and it prevents the chat from working when I load an external library.

I've been trying to fix this for 6 hours and I'm getting nowhere. I'd probably turn to just using DOM if nothing works =/.

Thank you for all that helped and if you need any information from me I'll gladly share it.

Comment: there may be a jquery conflict and you need to remove all the jquery links and include only one..like, `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.This may help

Comment: Do not try to use `unsafeWindow` with jQuery.  This works differently from browser to browser (and you didn't state which browser(s) you are using).  **Use [this technique, to use jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508)** -- which works well in all userscript-capable browsers.

Comment: Related: [jQuery in Greasemonkey 1.0 conflicts with websites using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at another userscript and this is the solution!

```
(function wrapper(window, injectNeeded, undefined) {

// Script injection if needed.
if (injectNeeded) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = '(' + wrapper + ')(window, false)';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.body.removeChild(script);
    return;
}

var $,
    jQuery;

$ = jQuery = window.jQuery;

 console.log($('a').length + "links on this page.");
})(this.unsafeWindow || window, window.chrome ? true : false);
```

Source: https://raw.github.com/cletusc/Userscript--Twitch-Chat-Emotes/master/script.user.js#bypass=true

Comment: Works for Google Chrome's TamperMonkey.

Comment: It won't around Chrome version 28 or so.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to avoid that, however the community I'm writing the script for keeps their browsers up to date and not many people will use it. I made it mainly for educational purposes and personal use.

Thank you for your useful information.