# getElementsByTagName error with Greasemonkey on a page based in extJS with simple use case

Tags: jquery, extjs, greasemonkey

I am working with using greasemonkey on a web-app that builds the DOM in stages with a lot of javascript and leverages the extJS library.

With no greasemonkey code running, the site obviously loads normally.

When I run this code (or any simple code like it):

```
jQuery( window ).load(function(){
    alert('some text');
});
```

I get the alert to pop up no problem, but then I get this error from firebug (and the rest of the application ceases to load):

TypeError: container.getElementsByTagName is not a function

which points to this line of code:

```
   var MktMainNav={
topTabId:'mktTopTabList',
notAllowedMsg:MktLang.getStr('nav.Limited_access'),
init:function(){
    var container=$(this.topTabId);
    if(container){
        var elts=container.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for(var i=0;i<elts.length;i++){
            var el=Ext.fly(elts[i]);el.on("click",this.click,elts[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I can't edit this code, as I am using greasemonkey to just try to change the look of the application.

It just seems weird to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code? It's missing 2 brackets (I just formatted it)

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code--that is the site's code which I can only look at, not edit--I am trying to overlay greasemonkey scripts, which I have done for many sites in the past, but this site in particular, the way it is constructed, is giving me a problem that I cannot figure out.

Comment: My guess is, somehow the alert is breaking the page code loading (I think alerts pause the page load)... do you get the problem if you do something other than an alert there?

Comment: Yes the alert was for simplicity in the example--it happens when i try and do anything.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use [`jQuery.load()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=load) -- which is an AJAX function.  Best guess, from the Q, is that you are trying to do:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function () {
        alert('some text');
    },
    false
);
```

Or:

```
jQuery (window).on ("load", function () {
    alert('some text 2');
} );
```

---

---

For anything else, we need to see the exact Greasemonkey script and the exact target page to be sure, but the most likely problem is some variation of `@grant none` interference.  See [jQuery in Greasemonkey 1.0 conflicts with websites using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508), for example.