# Why can't I generate a 'click' event directly from my user script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm making a script to interact with a web page. So, I need to generate click events.
(I'm using GreaseMonkey)

Well, my question is:

Why isn't this working from the user script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a:contains('example')").click();
});
```

- jQuery checked and tested. Working fine.
- It works from the console! But NOT from the script
- Everything else works...
- The target  has a `href="JavaScript:void(0)"` Could this be the problem?

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/h3YtJ/ Next time when you experience some issues with jquery - reproduce it on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: it does work... form the console, yes... but not from my script... like i said above!
how can i make it work from the user script in GreaseMonkey?

and the the target has a href="JavaScript:void(0)", not "#"....

Comment: Are you sure this is the part of the code that is not working?

Comment: i have removed EVERYTHING else! the script is 100% what is there!!!
on the console is a go... on the script is not!!

Comment: it's a security thing: maybe try unsafeWindow.setTimeout instead of $().ready()...

Answer (score 4):

jQuery `.click()`, like jQuery `.trigger()`, only works reliably with events handled by jQuery.  And in **the case of userscripts** and Greasemonkey scripts, the jQuery instance triggering click must be the same instance as the jQuery that set the event handler (usually).

Additionally, [userscript jQuery interferes with the target page unless you explicitly take countermeasures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).

There are two basic approaches in cases like this.  (1) Use `@grant none` mode, (2) properly sandbox your script and generate a true click event.

**(1) Quick and dirty `@grant none` method:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery;

$("a:contains('example')").click();
```

Warning: With this method, you cannot use the built-in `GM_` functions.  And, the page must be running jQuery to use jQuery functions.

**(2) Recommended click event method:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var targLink = $("a:contains('example')");

clickNode (targLink);

function clickNode (jNode) {
    if (jNode  &&  jNode.length) {
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
```

---

Note that `$(document).ready()` is not needed in Greasemonkey scripts except when `@run-at document-start` is set.

Comment: Thank you, i'll only be able to test that tomorrow, but it sounds right 'cause i just changed the "@grant" before running the script for the 1st time... i'll definitely try that! ;)

Comment: I've tried the 1st approach... the page doesn't load properly!
(everything is in place, but it stays with the 'loading...' message, doesn't move from there!)
With the 2nd approach, doesn't happen anything... i also tried to call the `clickNode` function from a `setTimeout`, just to be sure it runs after the page is loaded, but nothing happens!...

Comment: Do you advise me to use "Scriptish" instead of "GreaseMonkey" has a definitive way to solve this?

Comment: No.  If this doesn't work in GM, it won't work in Scriptish either. Something you are not showing us is the problem.  Remember that `:contains()` is case-sensitive.  Link to the target page.

Comment: You're right...
On Scriptish, it works only when i run the script from the editor... when i run the script from the page it doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

Your script does nothing because of `javascript:void(0)`. `click` event is triggered but there is no action after that.

If you change it to

```
<body>
  <a href="style.css">example</a>

  <script>
  $("a:contains('example')").click();
  </script>
</body>
```

you will get, for example, file `style.css` open.

Comment: Ok, 1st part of the question is answered...

2nd part is:

The page isn't mine, so i can't change anything...
I'm just interacting with it... clicking and analyzing the results...

How can i click effectively on that <a> without changing the attribute?