# Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey only running in iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I don't know why, but my greasemonkey/tampermonkey script refuses to run on pages that have an iframe.
The script runs inside the iframe, but not on the root domain. If I use the @noframes option, nothing happens at all on pages with an iframe.

I've even resorted to
`// @match      http://*/*`

My test code is very simple...

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)

var title = $('title').html();
alert(title);
```

This will show an alert with the name of the iframe, but not the actual site. I've tried it in both greasemonkey and tampermonkey.

Comment: i'm trying to access the parent page, not the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your target parent page may not have an actual `<head>` element,
   causing that script-instance to crash.
2. **That is not how you add jQuery with a script!**  You will have all manner of timing issues and code conflicts.
   See the second part of [this answer for the best cross-platform way to add jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508) (But overkill if you just use GM/TM).  And [this bit for resolving jQuery conflicts and crashes in GM/TM scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255424/331508).

   It may be that the iframes load jQuery on their own, or you just have a happy timing accident (for now), but don't rely on such luck for your code.
3. The script metadata section / header is *crucial* for questions like this.  Your question needs to show the whole script.
   The errors from the *Browser Console* and a link to the target page would not be amiss either.

If the script is for Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey (no plain Chrome), this will work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var title = $('title').html();
alert(title);
```

Comment: Originally i was using that code to add jquery because i was using the chrome console, not tampermonkey. Thanks for the info about the @require tag, though. It works perfectly.