# Greasemonkey script blocking other scripts of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

My Greasemonkey script works  exactly as I want it to by but it somehow blocks javascripts from the website itself. They just don't work anymore.

I use the very useful [waitForKeyElements()](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) to start some actions after a certain container has been loaded.

What is disturbing the other scripts?

```
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant           none
// ==/UserScript==

var newText = 'changed';

// changes after loading .containerid
waitForKeyElements (
    "#containerid", renameTop
);

function renameTop() {
    var searchlinkTop = document.getElementById('containerid'); 
        searchlinkTop.innerHTML = newText;  
}

// some normal changes

function waitForKeyElements (
// ... the script's content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["jQuery in Greasemonkey 1.0 conflicts..."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255424/331508).
The problem is the `@grant none`.  This is a *very* poorly though-out "feature" of Greasemonkey that guarantees that you will have conflicts and errors.  You're just lucky that *this time* it was so obvious and immediate.

Change `@grant none` to `@grant GM_addStyle`.  This will restore the sandbox and remove the conflict.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It worked for this script.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It worked perfectly for my little script.
But I've another bigger script that also suffers from this problem for months. Of course I just tried your advice there too, but it breaks the whole script...? Are there any exceptions to this approach?

The bigger script uses e.g.
// @require http://github.com/sizzlemctwizzle/GM_config/raw/master/gm_config.js
GM_xmlhttpRequest({method: "GET",
  url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js',
  onload: ...;}});
GM_registerMenuCommand(...);
window.addEventListener ("load",Gm_main,false);
$('div.twitter').remove();

Comment: That second script uses several `GM_` functions.  You need to add a `@grant` directive for each `GM_` function.  Other than that, open a new question for the second script (after check-marking this answer as the answer).

Comment: Thank you! A added all grants to the second script but it still didn't work. Turned out it only didn't work when I tried to modify the content of the postloaded container. No idea why, but I workarounded it...