# How do I use Greasemonkey and Jquery to hide an HTML element with a certain class?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

This [news site](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/feb/25/bitcoin-exchange-mtgox-offline-amid-rumours-of-theft) (The Guardian) has a small frame that displays in the bottom-right of the page, with code like this:

```
<div class="initially-off social-cta-overlay">

    <div class="social-cta-overlay-content"></div>

</div>
```

I hid the internal contents of the inner `div` because they're not important. I wrote a Greasemonkey script that uses JQuery to hide this box because it appears on every page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        hide-guardian-ad
// @namespace   guardian
// @description Hides the Guardian social media frame
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js

$(".social-cta-overlay").hide()
```

I installed the script, but nothing happens and the box is still there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That script has 3 problems (worst first):

1. The `@require` directive is outside [the metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).  This means that Greasemonkey ignores it as just an ordinary javascript comment.
2. There is no `@include` or `@match` directive. This means that the script will fire on every page and iframe of every site!  (Crashing some of them, and chewing up resources.)
3. `@grant none` means that [the script will interfere with and crash all or part of many sites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).

This script works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        hide-guardian-ad
// @include     http://www.theguardian.com/*
// @description Hides the Guardian social media frame
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

$(".social-cta-overlay").hide()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I presume `GM_addStyle` does exactly what it sounds like: gives the script permission to add styles *only*? (I couldn't find that specific option in [the documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant)).

Comment: Yes.  Here is [the doc for `GM_addStyle`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle).  It's harmless to grant it in almost all cases, and doing so switches the sandbox back on.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a semicolon at the end?  This doesn't work for me, for the top banner of theguardian.com, anyway :/  I've not found any way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).find(".social-cta-overlay").hide();
```

Comment: As you can see from the other answer this is incorrect, since my script had quite a few problems.