# Greasemonkey script won't append to id

Tags: jquery, append, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write my first Greasemonkey script, and I'm not sure why it isn't working. The alerts display what they should, but the `.append` doesn't work. I'm running the script from my local machine for now on a non-local site.

Why might it not be working?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LootTracker
// @namespace   Kong
// @include     http://www.kongregate.com/games/5thPlanetGames/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

alert('1');
LootTabHeaderText = "<li id='loot_tab'></li>";
alert(LootTabHeaderText);
$("#main_tab_set").append(LootTabHeaderText); //doesn't fire
```

Comment: You might need to load jQuery to get that working... see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/8890387)

Comment: Thanks, Mottie! This is in Firefox, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target site already uses jQuery and your script is loading a different jQuery on top of it. [Loading jQuery in `@grant none` mode busts the page, or the script, or both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).

**Additionally:**

1. The node with the id `main_tab_set` is not always present and is probably added via AJAX. You need AJAX techniques for that.
2. The node may be in an iFrame.  You'd need to adjust the script's `@include` statements for that.

(Note that in 60 seconds of poking around, I did not see that node at all.)

So, Change the script to this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LootTracker
// @namespace   Kong
// @include     http://www.kongregate.com/games/5thPlanetGames/*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
console.log ('1');
LootTabHeaderText = "<li id='loot_tab'>Loot tab</li>";
console.log (LootTabHeaderText);

waitForKeyElements ("#main_tab_set", appendListItem);

function appendListItem (jNode) {
    jNode.append (LootTabHeaderText); 
    console.log ("Node found!");
}
```

That will work unless the content is in an iframe. In that case, adjust the `@include`s to fire on the iframe.

Open the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) to see the debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Your event do fire but the element is not there. Here is a working code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LootTracker
// @namespace   Kong
// @include     http://www.kongregate.com/games/5thPlanetGames/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

// Page elements must load first
// On page load run this code
$(function(){
  checkDOMChange();
});

var times = 0;
function checkDOMChange()
{
  // If there is no menu
  if( $("#main_tab_set").length==0 ){
    times++;
    if(times<=100) // Give 10secs max
     setTimeout( checkDOMChange, 100 );

  }else{

    // Now Lets make the menu tab
    LootTabHeaderText = '<li class="tab" id="loot_tab"><a href="#loot_tab_pane" class="">Loot</a></li>';
    $("#main_tab_set").append(LootTabHeaderText);

  }
}
```

Happy coding