# Script works in Greasemonkey, but nothing happens in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

The below script works in Firefox/Greasemonkey, but nothing happens in Chrome/Tampermonkey.

Can anyone see why it doesn't work in Tampermonkey?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Example
// @namespace   Example.com
// @description Example.com
// @include     https://example.com/*
// @include     http://example.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5392-waitforkeyelements/code/WaitForKeyElements.js?version=115012
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('close-cookies').click();
};

waitForKeyElements('div.survey16', removeSurvey);

function removeSurvey() {
  document.getElementById('survey16').hide();
}

$('.chat-bot').hide();
```

Comment: if you put some `console.log` is it logged into console? what if you remove some `@require`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question code should not work in either browser and you should see error messages in the consoles.

Problems:

1. `document.getElementById('survey16')` [does not have a `.hide()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).  That's a jQuery function.
2. `removeSurvey()` should be:

   ```
   function removeSurvey (jNode) {
       jNode.hide ();  //-- .hide is a jQuery function.
   }
   ```
3. EXCEPT, there is a mismatch between the `waitForKeyElements` call and `removeSurvey`.
   In the first you are searching for a div with *class* `survey16`, but in the second you are trying to delete an element with the *id* `survey16`.  Which is it?
4. As a general rule, don't use `@grant none` when also using `@require`, this usually leads to page conflicts and crashes. [jQuery is especially bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery)
5. Also, `@grant none` functions slightly differently in both browsers.  When using `@require`, specify `@grant GM_addStyle` except in special, and rare, cases.

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of a way to debug what `jNode` contains? I don't suppose you use `console.log` for this?

Comment: jNode is always a standard [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). And, yes, you can console.log it.