# Add text value of a node as css-class to a parent element, using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

The target page HTML looks like:

```
<div class="conversation"> 
    <div class="subject"> 
        <div class="labels"> 
            <div title="Tag1" class="labelsElement-label"> 
                <span class="labelsElement-name">Tag1</span> 
            </div>
            <div title="Tag2" class="labelsElement-label"> 
                <span class="labelsElement-name">Tag2</span> 
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

When ever a `span.labelsElement-name` is somewhere **I'd like to add its contents to the parent `div.conversion` as a class.** Like:

change:

```
<div class="conversation">
```

in the first row to:

```
<div class="conversation Tag1 Tag2">
```

because these two values are in the two nested `span.labelsElement-name`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lucumt said, [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) is great for this kind as it makes manipulating pages (the DOM) a snap.

Using jQuery in a userscript has been covered in numerous posts. See [*this answer* for the most robust way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255424/331508). (Use `@require` and `@grant`.)

**A complete script** that adds CSS classes based on that tag text is (Just the first gray block):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add CSS classes based on select node contents.
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".labelsElement-name", taggifyParentNode);

function taggifyParentNode (jNode) {
    var tagName = jNode.text ().trim ();
    jNode.closest (".conversation").addClass (tagName);
}
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------*/
/*--- Simulated target page follows: ---*/
/*--------------------------------------*/
.Tag1 {background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5); }
.Tag2 {background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
.Tag1.Tag2 {background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5); }
.conversation, .labels > div {
    margin: 1ex 1em;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
.labels > div {padding: 1ex 1em;  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//greasyfork.org/scripts/2199-waitforkeyelements/code/waitForKeyElements.js"></script>
<div class="conversation"> <div class="subject">
    <div class="labels">
        <div title="Tag1"><span class="labelsElement-name">Tag1</span></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
<div class="conversation"> <div class="subject">
    <div class="labels">
        <div title="Tag2"><span class="labelsElement-name">Tag2</span></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
<div class="conversation"> <div class="subject">
    <div class="labels">
        <div title="Tag1"><span class="labelsElement-name">Tag1</span></div>
        <div title="Tag2"><span class="labelsElement-name">Tag2</span></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Run the code snippet to see it in action.

`waitForKeyElements()` is used in case the target page is dynamic (AJAX-driven), which seems likely.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have to understand this @grand thing, but it works and all the rest is understood. many kudos

Comment: You're welcome!  In this case, `@grant` just keeps the userscript and the target page from conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `addClass` to do it:

```
   $("span.labelsElement-name").each(function(index,element){
     var text = $.trim($(element).text());
     $(".conversation").addClass(text);
   });
```

Available demo is at https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/45269/

Comment: jQuery? The likes of Tampermonkey do only run plain Javascript, don't they?

Comment: I think jQuery is the simplest solution for it

Comment: OK understand. But I want to do this with Tampermonkey like I said in my question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Good start, but what happens if there is more than one `.conversation` node? -- which seems very possible.  Also, jQuery is not available in GM/TM/userscript engines/scenarios, unless your script makes it so.