# Is the Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) pattern really necessary when writing userscripts?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tampermonkey, userscripts, greasemonkey-4

My question is quite similar to [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/3258851), however it concerns userscripts (specifically for GreaseMonkey) instead.

I see that some userscripts are distributed with this pattern, and some are not.

Example of script with the IIFE pattern: [(source)](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/19220-sort-facebook-newsfeed-by-most-recent/code)

```
// ==UserScript==
// (...)
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    // if <condition>
        document.location.href += '?sk=h_chr';
    // ...
})();
```

Example of script without it: [(source)](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/153075)

```
// ==UserScript==
// (...)
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/?sk=h_chr";
```

In addition, I also found that the "New script" template from TamperMonkey follows it, while the templates from GreaseMonkey and ViolentMonkey do not.

The question is, then, is the IIFE pattern any useful when writing userscripts?

Especially, if my script is in [`strict` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and I use `let` instead of `var`. In any case, as far as I know, functions and variables defined in userscripts are not made available in the global page scope.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't think so - taking the code from an IIFE and just running it is exactly the same (except some things like recursion).

Comment: What if you add a variable later? IIFEs are a good practice and you gain nothing from not using 
them.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Assuming they have no practical purpose at all (i.e. are functionally equivalent, 100%, *for userscripts*), I gain points for the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, and perhaps others as well.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I don't dispute that but maintenability is more important.

Comment: @AluanHaddad then you have to agree that, given two pieces of code that are functionally equivalent, the one with two less statements that did nothing in the first place is more maintainable.

Comment: TM userscripts appear to already run in strict mode by default - separate userscripts running on the same page will not be interfered with if one script has `use strict` and another doesn't. Also, `var`s on the top level inside a userscript don't look to be assigned to the window regardless, even with `@grant none`, so it doesn't look to avoid globals either. I see no benefit to the IIFE, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @Marc.2377 I don't agree because the person coming after you may not understand what IIFEs even are. I'm sorry, but I cannot tell you how many programmers get JavaScript wrong to this day. If userscripts are automatically scoped, that would change things.

Comment: One very, very small benefit might be that, when copying over code, the `use strict` inside an IIFE will help avoid the linter warning *in the IDE you're writing the code in*, if you happen to be using an IDE with a linter. (and the explicitly stated `use strict` helps tell the IDE that the code below should be interpreted as being in strict mode.) But that's very tenuous.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, TM scripts do NOT run in strict mode by default.  But there is an advanced setting that can be set to `Always`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no; the IIFE pattern is seldom useful for wrapping a whole userscript (see edge cases below).  That's a throwback to many years ago when some engines (briefly) did not wrap scripts by default.

In fact, if you include the obsolete [`@unwrap` directive](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_unwrap), the script engines will all now ignore it.

Here are some reasons to use the IIFE pattern:

- It was the only way to enforce `strict` mode in old versions of Violentmonkey (2018 or earlier) for the whole script.
- It can **squelch a harmless** `Parsing error: 'return' outside of function` **warning** if you use BOTH:  (1) A script-wide `return` and (2) an external LINTer.
  Some old Greasemonkey versions would also warn about this, while still working perfectly.
- (I thought there was a 3rd edge case. But got interrupted and can't remember what it was.)

**Consider this test script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Scope and Strict-Mode Demo script
// @match    https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @unwrap
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, curly */
'use strict';

if (location.pathname.includes("/users/") ) {
    console.log ("Terminating script early.");
    return;  // In external LINTers, this will cause a harmless warning.
}

var cantSeeMeInConsole      = "neener neener";
window.canSomestimesSeeMe   = "Howdy";

console.log (`In Strict mode: ${bInStrictMode() }; \`cantSeeMeInConsole\`: ${cantSeeMeInConsole}`);

function bInStrictMode () {
    var inStrict = false;
    var dummyObj = {};
    Object.defineProperty (dummyObj, 'foo', {value: "bar", writable: false } );

    try { dummyObj.foo = "fee"; }
    catch (e) { inStrict = true; }
    return inStrict;
}
```

- Run on Firefox and Chrome.
- Safari and Opera should give same results.
- Microsoft Edge *probably* gives same results. <sup><sub>(But I don't care much if it doesn't.)</sub></sup>
- Run using Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, and Greasemonkey 4.

#### Script scoping:

In all cases, the userscript is scoped/wrapped.  The page can't see code, nor variables like `cantSeeMeInConsole`.
Beware that [script page conflicts can still occur in `@grant none` mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery)

#### Script sandboxing:

Additional isolations apply, depending on: (a) the userscript engine, (b) the browser, and (c) the `@grant` mode.
For example, using Greasemonkey, or changing the grant mode kills the page's ability to see `canSomestimesSeeMe`.

#### Strict mode:

- Placing `'use strict';` up top like that switches the whole userscript into strict mode.
- Additionally, in Tampermonkey's advanced options, you can set "strict mode" to [Default/Always/Disabled] for all scripts.

---

In a related note, if the script does not use `@run-at` settings, there is no point in using `$(document).ready()` or its shorthand.

Answer (score -3):

> functions and variables defined in userscripts are not made available in the global page scope

This is not true.

The way userscripts work is via script injection (yes, it's basically an attack). The only way userscripts can get access to variables and functions in the page is to expose userscripts to the page - thus the page has access to the userscript.

Therefore the main reason to use an IIFE in userscripts is to avoid messing up scripts running on the page.

Some script injection system **may** transparently execute your userscript in an IIFE behind your back (this is what nodejs does with modules - yes, it's not a userscript system but it is an example of software that does this). In such cases you don't need to manually code the IIFE yourself. I personally don't know which extension does this and which does not so I tend to include the IIFE just to be safe.

If your code does not define any new variables or functions you also can get away with not using an IIFE because there is nothing in your code that can override existing code.

Comment: This is wrong.  All major userscript engines (Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, and equivalents) scope their scripts at a minimum. Functionally, they are in IIFE's by default.  In addition, depending on the platform and the `@grant` mode, the scripts may be in various sandboxes -- with even more restrictions and effectively no chance that the page script can directly (be) interfere(d) (with). ... Unfortunately, the details vary across browser and script engine and effective grant mode, so there's about 12+ variations on the actual isolation, but IIFE is always there.