# UserScript - How can I know one user has installed the Tampermonkey or not?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, tampermonkey, userscripts

I develop a UserScript and wrote a document for how install it. I found the procedure is too hard for user, so I willing make a script in website to install them automatically.

My plan:

- Get browser info from user and open the Tampermonkey extention page(chrome webstore or AMO)
- When the Tampermonkey had installed, open a page whick URL ends with '.user.js'

The problem is how can I get "When the Tampermonkey had installed"?

Comment: If there were such a way it'd be a security hole in Tampermonkey which should be fixed. The only sites that can detect Tampermonkey are greasyfork.org, tampermonkey.net, userstyles.org whitelisted in its source code https://puu.sh/Ehp9g/e40620ccbb.png

Comment: @wOxxOm Why? I even can get what plugins user installed though `navigator.plugins` but extentions

Comment: Plugins are exposed via standard web API so it's unrelated. As for Tampermonkey, I guess it's because it's often used to modify the behavior of pages so there are quite a few authors who would block that if they could.

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821042/can-a-webpage-detect-a-tampermonkey-userscript. and others.